# How to spy just one call of ActiveSupport::Notifications #instrument, not all of them

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot, activesupport, rspec-mocks

I'm making a Rspec test that checks if `ActiveSupport::Notification.instrument` was called with some parameters.

The thing is that in order to make this test a need `FactoryBot` to build some objects, but when I try to spy on `ActiveSupport::Notification.instrument` I always get an error:

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications received :instrument with unexpected arguments
         expected: (:asd)
              got: ("factory_bot.run_factory", {:factory=>#<FactoryBot::Factory:0x005569b6d30, @al... nil, dispatch: nil, distribution_state: 2, main_category_id: nil>}, :strategy=>:build, :traits=>[]})
```

It seems that FactoryBot calls activesupport so when I mock it for my test purpose I end up mocking it too far...

code example:

class:

```
class SomeObject
    def initialize(something)
        #some code
    end

    def my_method
        ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument :asd
    end
end
```

spec:

```
describe "#my_method" do
    let(:some_object) { build :some_object }
    before do
      allow(ActiveSupport::Notifications).to receive(:instrument).with :asd
    end

    it "calls notifier" do
      described_class.new(some_object).my_method

      expect(ActiveSupport::Notifications).to have_received(:instrument).with :asd
    end
  end
```

How can I just mock my call and not FactoryBot's .

I only manage that with one more `allow` before the one that mocks `:asd`:

```
 allow(ActiveSupport::Notifications).to receive(:instrument).and_call_original
```

Is there another(better) way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to avoid mocking in general.

I had a similar problem and here's how I achieved it:

```
  describe "#my_method" do
    let(:some_object) { build :some_object }

    before { record_events }

    it "calls notifier" do
      described_class.new(some_object).my_method

      # Make sure your event was triggered
      expect(events.map(&:name)).to include('asd')

      # Check number of events
      expect(events).to be_one

      # Check contents of event payload                  
      expect(events.first.payload).to eq({ 'extra' => 'context' })

      # Even check the duration of an event
      expect(events.first.duration).to be < 3
    end

    private

    attr_reader :events

    def record_events
      @events = []
      ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe(:asd) do |*args| #
        @events << ActiveSupport::Notifications::Event.new(*args)
      end
    end
  end
```

### Advantages over mocking

- No more weird side effects
- Using `ActiveSupport::Notifications` as intended
- [`ActiveSupport::Notifications::Event`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/94b5cd3a20edadd6f6b8cf0bdf1a4d4919df86cb/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb#L54) wrapper gives you nice extras like [`#duration`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/94b5cd3a20edadd6f6b8cf0bdf1a4d4919df86cb/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb#L80)
- Easily check for other events being triggered
- The ability to only look at events that match a name - use `ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe(/asd/)` to do partial matches on event names
- Better readability - checking events array is more readable

### Disadvantages over mocking

- Way more code
- Mutates the `@events` array
- Possible dependencies between tests if you don't clear `@events` on `teardown`